# Do I need to reinstall everything to upgrade from 13.10 to 14.10?

Tags: upgrade

The title almost explains it all. If I update from 13.10 to 14.10, do I need to reinstall software such as Apache, PHP, Filezilla and everything I've already installed? I've recently moved to Ubuntu and I wouldn't like to go through that process again.

Comment: No, all software should remain installed. Some old packages may be removed, but you will have the option to not remove them (this is usually not anything you would use a lot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will remain with all software if you use this the method in this post. It works the same way for upgrading to 14.04 Final

http://itsfoss.com/upgrade-ubuntu-1404-beta-1310/

Using a live USB is a bit complicated and may wipe everything out if you make one mistake.